# Cancelling ongoing Angular $http requests when there's a new request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does one cancel an ongoing Angular $http request when there's a new request?

I've got an Angular app with a view that updates live as the user types. Sometimes old requests complete after the latest request, meaning the view displays the wrong data. What's the most straightforward way to cancel the previous request when there's a new one?

Using Angular 1.5, for what it's worth.

```
<input ng-model = "query" ng-keyup = "search()"/>
{{results | json}}

// In the controller:
    $scope.search = function(){
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/endpoint.php"
            params: {
                query: $scope.query
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.results = response.data;
        })
    }
```

One solution I have tried:

```
// In the controller:
    var canceler = $q.resolve();    // New
    $scope.search = function(){
        canceler.resolve("Canceling old request");     // New
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/endpoint.php"
            params: {
                query: $scope.query
            },
            timeout: canceler.promise    // New
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.results = response.data;
        })
    }
```

In this scenario, even though I'm calling canceler.resolve before the $http request, the request turns up as "failed".

Any insights?

**edit: Solution found!**

```
// In the controller:
    var canceler = $q.defer();

    $scope.search = function(){
        canceler.resolve("cancelled"); // Resolve the previous canceler
        canceler = $q.defer();        // Important: Create a new canceler! 
                                      // Otherwise all $http requests made will fail
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/endpoint.php"
            params: {
                query: $scope.query
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.results = response.data;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to set up the promise, then with each search() cancel it and reinitialize a new one. This will reliably cancel any previous $http():

```
var canceler = $q.defer();

$scope.search = function() {

    canceler.resolve();

    canceler = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/endpoint.php"
        params: {
            query: $scope.query
        }
        timeout: canceler.promise
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.results = response.data;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 12):

When you start a new search, call the `cancel()` function. And you can use a `resolved` variable to make sure that you do not abort your `$http` call before it starts. Something like this:

```
var canceler = $q.defer();
var resolved = false;

var cancel = function() {
    canceler.resolve("http call aborted");
};

$scope.search = function() {
    if (resolved) {
        cancel();
    }

    canceler = $q.defer();
    resolved = true;

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/endpoint.php"
        params: {
            query: $scope.query
        }
        timeout: canceler.promise
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.results = response.data;
        resolved = false;
    })
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$q` in your controller/directive/service.

Comment: Hmm - I try this- `ng-click = "cancel(); search();"` and I still get the same XHR failed in my console. I'm injecting $q, too.

Comment: @schnauss are you using var canceler = $q.resolve() or var canceler = $q.defer();?

Comment: `var canceler = $q.defer();`. I'm stumped.

Comment: According to your code, the canceler is already resolved before you do http call.

Comment: Hm. Wouldn't I want to do that in order to cancel the previous request, if any?

Comment: @schnauss can you try my answer again, i just add a "resolved" variable to make sure that you dont abort the http call before it starts. I think this time it should work. Please make sure you have the right logic of when to set resolved=true in your code.

Comment: No luck, I still get the "XHR failed loading" error.

Comment: I found the solution: I had to create a new canceler with each search request, otherwise it would always fail.